# When running my Flutter MacOs app through VSCode, my debug console prints thousands of lines

Tags: flutter, macos, debugging, console

Could someone please assist. I updated my MacOs and after updating, when running my flutter Mac app, my debug console goes crazy. I have updated flutter, updated my pub spec and flutter doctor gives all checks. I have no idea what this could be and searching the internet hasn't given me any form of direction. I would be so appreciative if someone would be able to point me in the right direction or if you have a solution. I am unable to build and debug my app with all this text in my debug console.

Worth mentioning I get the exact same issue when running a fresh flutter project and I only get this on macOS. iOs, android and web works fine.

[image]

Comment: Try Restart or Flutter Clean

Comment: 1 - What's your Flutter version?
2 - The version of your mac?
3 - Is it a freshly created app our existing app?

Comment: It's an existing app running on flutter channel stable 3.7.2. Running MacOS Ventura 13.2

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper I have tried this and It didn't work but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @gausoft It's an existing app running on flutter channel stable 3.7.2. Running MacOS Ventura 13.2

Answer (score 0):

To save others' time of clicking the link above - this issue is related to the "Hide Menubar" option in MacOS Settings. (Settings -> Desktop & Dock -> Automatically hide and show the menu bar)

Values "In Full Screen Only" or "Never" show stop this output.